# express-ejs-layout: how to set default view if no view was passed

Tags: html, layout, express, ejs

I have another dilemma: I have a default title and I want rewrite it in some views. The solution that works for me now is:

```
<%- defineContent('title') %>
<title>Title</title>
```

So views in which I rewrite the title look like:

```
<title>Title</title>
<title>Login</title>
```

I'm looking for more clean way to do things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defineContent` helper defines a content area, but doesn't take what you write next as default. It is merely a placeholder. There is currently no support for content areas with defaults in `express-ejs-layout`.

You could define title like this:

```
<title><%= title || 'Title' %></title>
```

And send in a different title in the locals object for the views where you want to overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite clean solution